# Como colocar legenda para fora do gráfico HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Alguém[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] sabe como coloco essa legenda para fora do meu gráfico?

//Create the chart

```
    Highcharts.stockChart('grafico_relatorio', {

            legend: {
                enabled: true
            },

            scrollbar: false,

            exporting: {

                filename: nome_da_exportacao,

                    chartOptions: {

                            legend: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            //inputEnabled: false
                            rangeSelector: false,
                            scrollbar: false,
                            navigator: false

                    }
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 5,

                buttons: [{

                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'Tudo'

                }, {

                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1h'

                },{

                    type: 'hour',
                    count: 12,
                    text: '12h'

                },{

                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'

                },{

                    type: 'day',
                    count: 7,
                    text: '7d'

                },{

                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'

                }]
            },

            credits: {

                text: 'InMetrics',

                position: {

                    align: 'right',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 5
                },

                style: {
                    fontSize: '1em',
                }
            },

            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },

             tooltip: {
               shared: true
            },

            series: seriesOptions,

            yAxis: { //--- Primary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: metrica
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'right'
                },
                gridLineColor: '#b1b7b0',
                gridLineWidth: 2
            }           

    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: vc quer colocar o `bytes recived` pro lado direito? qual o tipo de gráfico é esse? poderia adicionar o código fonte que monta ele?

Comment: Oi meu amigo, na verdade quero colocar os dados (500, 400,300,200,100) para fora do grafico. ele é montado utilizando a api do highcharts (vou mandar o codigo que o gera)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na documentação você pode fazer essa modificação com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
yAxis:{
    labels: {
        x:20
    }
}
```

Ficaria desta maneira:

```
yAxis: { //--- Primary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: metrica
                },
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x:20
                },
                gridLineColor: '#b1b7b0',
                gridLineWidth: 2
            }
```

Referencias: [Link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.labels), [Link2](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes)

Comment: Jonathan valeu cara, isso mesmo que eu estava precisando

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do eixo Y adicione a propriedade  `opposite: true` isso vai intever os valores e a legenda do lado esquerdo para o direito.

```
yAxis: {
        opposite: true,

        title: {text: metrica},
        labels: {align: 'right'},
        gridLineColor: '#b1b7b0',
        gridLineWidth: 2
}
```

Comment: Orra ! ai sim, deu certo pena que ainda não tenho reputação!

Comment: @JulioHenrique97 logo você consegue aumentar a pontuação, nesse caso você pode marcar como aceita (sinal verde) a resposta que resolveu o seu problema.

Comment: acabei de ver, valeu! agora estou procurando como definir a largura do grafico gerado, pois ele esta deixando as labels para fora da div, e ai nao aparece na tela

Comment: sabe como faço pra definir a largura do gráfico? vou postar uma foto pra te mostrar o que acontece

Comment: sim, pq a div é independente (olha a imagem)

Comment: achei! é margin right do chart